# PostgreSQL update problems with uuid

Tags: centos, postgresql, uuid

I am trying to run yum update on my CentOS 5.2 box and keep getting this message:

Missing Dependency: libossp-uuid.so.15 is needed by package postgresql-contrib

I ran yum update postgresql separately and now it's 8.3.8. I also downloaded uuid-1.6.2 and built it from source, but I still get the same result.

yum update -d6 uuid gives me this at the end:

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package uuid.i386 0:1.6.1-3.el5.kb set to be updated
Checking deps for uuid.i386 0-1.6.1-3.el5.kb - u
Checking deps for uuid.i386 0-1.5.1-4.rhel5 - None
postgresql-contrib requires: libossp-uuid.so.15
--> Processing Dependency: libossp-uuid.so.15 for package: postgresql-contrib
Needed Require is not a package name. Looking up: libossp-uuid.so.15
Potential Provider: uuid.i386 0:1.5.1-4.rhel5
Mode is u for provider of libossp-uuid.so.15: uuid.i386 0:1.5.1-4.rhel5
Mode for pkg providing libossp-uuid.so.15: u
Cannot find an update path for dep for: libossp-uuid.so.15
Searching pkgSack for dep: libossp-uuid.so.15
Potential match for libossp-uuid.so.15 from uuid - 1.5.1-4.rhel5.i386
Matched uuid - 1.5.1-4.rhel5.i386 to require for libossp-uuid.so.15
uuid - 1.5.1-4.rhel5.i386 is in providing packages but it is already installed, removing.
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Dependency Process ending
Error: Missing Dependency: libossp-uuid.so.15 is needed by package postgresql-contrib
```

How can I resolve this situation?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If going to postgresql 8.4 is acceptable I would recommend trying yum install postgresql84.

If you do not need the contrib RPM (it is not necessary by default), first remove it: rpm -e postgresql-contrib, then perform the update.

HTH,
Neal

Answer (score 0):

Snag and install this guy:

http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/uuid-1.5.1-3.el5.i386.rpm

rpm -Uvh uuid-1.5.1-3.el5.i386.rpm

This *should* update the contrib RPM.

Comment: Unfortunately...

rpm -Uvh uuid-1.5.1-3.el5.i386.rpm
warning: uuid-1.5.1-3.el5.i386.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 217521f6
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package uuid-1.5.1-4.rhel5 (which is newer than uuid-1.5.1-3.el5) is already installed

Comment: I tried rpm -e --nodeps  uuid-1.5.1-4.rhel5 and then installing 1.5.1.-3 - still 'missing dependency'.

Comment: `yum --enablerepo=epel install uuid`